# Unix Shell Script as UDF for Pig and Hive

Tags: shell, unix, hive, apache-pig

Can we use unix shell script instead of using (Java or Python) for User Defined in Apache Pig and Hive?

If it is possible how can we mention in Hive Query or Pig script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't use unix shell script as Pig UDF.  Pig UDFs are currently supported only in six languages: `Java, Jython, Python, JavaScript, Ruby and Groovy.`

Please refer this link for more details
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/udf.html