# Unix Shell Script as UDF for Hive

Tags: shell, unix, hive, hiveql

I want to know can we create UDF for hive using shell script .For pig i got the reference from here [Unix Shell Script as UDF for Pig and Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415656/unix-shell-script-as-udf-for-pig-and-hive)That we can't create .
If we can create please let me know how we can create and the way we use it.

Comment: Shell is not a **programming** language, but a **command** language! Don't try to write an application by using shell!

Answer (score 0):

You can't write a hive UDF as a shell script as hive UDFs are [expected to come from jars](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HivePlugins) and can only be written in java or scala.

However, you can use a shell script in [`TRANSFORM`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Transform#LanguageManualTransform-TRANSFORMExamples).